# How to save the data from GZIPPED file by converting to JSON into ADLS

Tags: azure, https, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

I have an Event HUB which will receive GZIPPED Json Data as Messages. Any idea on how to catch these message and save the JSON to ADLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) feature.

Azure Event Hubs enables you to automatically capture the streaming data in Event Hubs in an Azure Blob storage or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 1 or Gen 2 account of your choice.

You can follow the official MS docs to further [Setting up Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#setting-up-event-hubs-capture)

### To Capture data to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 using Azure portal

(this is not available in basic namespace pricing, choose atleat standard plan)

**1.** Once you have the event hub namespace, create an event hub, while
creating select the **enable capture**

[image]

**2.** Later you can find and configure it at

```
Event hubs instance > features > Capture
```

[image]

**Note:**

> If you enable the Capture feature for an existing event hub, the
> feature captures events that arrive at the event hub after the feature
> is turned on. It doesn't capture events that existed in the event hub
> before the feature was turned on.

Comment: By doing this , it saving the files as avro and the format of data inside is changed to binary , any idea how to get my data into original format of gzipped JSON.

Comment: yes, further reading into [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#use-avro-tools), you can also use [Avro Tools](https://downloads.apache.org/avro/stable/java/) to convert the file to JSON format and perform other processing.

Comment: I posted this regarding help for , how to extract that gziped json data from Event hub messages. Still not able to find the solution.